# How to use CancellationTokenSource in IMemoryCache to Invalidate desired cache items?

Tags: caching, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-6.0, cancellationtokensource, memorycache

I have a CMS web application in ASP.NET Core 6 MVC. It has functionality to create content and publish to live website. Currently I'm using `IMemoryCache` as a caching mechanism and when I'm editing any content or doing some changes, I'm adding it to the cache. At the time of publish this cached content is not flushed out.

Now what I want is to track the content that is contained within a cached object, so that at publish time, we can smartly invalidate the cache of any object that references content that may have changed with a publish.

I have a simple way to do this: each time we write to cache, we should also write an object that describes the content inside.

Pseudo code example of this:

```cs
public class CacheContentIndex
{
    // Start with this
    List<int> ContentIDs;

    // Examples of objects we could track in the future
    List<int> ContentMenuIDs;
    List<int> ContentMediaIDs;
}
```

Each time you make a call to `CacheHelper.Add()`, we should be passing in an extra parameter that takes an object of type `CacheContentIndex()`. As we’re going through a function, we should loop through the results, identify what these ID’s are, and then put them into that object.

When `CacheHelper.Add()` gets an object of type `CacheContentIndex`, under the hood, you should just save that to cache with a common prefix to the `CacheKey` that was passed in

Example: if the cache key passed in was `MainMenu`, you should make a cache save with the key `CacheContentIndex_MainMenu`.

At publish time, we'll need to:

- Identify each ID that gets touched as part of the publish (basically everything tracked in a `CacheContentIndex` object)
- Make an outgoing web request to each publish endpoint to a common path where we POST an object that has all of those ID’s. Example path: `/cacheinvalidate`
- When requests come into that `/cacheinvalidate` path on the live websites, the following happens:

1. Iterate through the values of all cache keys that start with `CacheContentIndex_`.
2. In each, check to see if it has any content that matches what we are being told to invalidate.
   Example: Say we have a `cachekey` called `MainMenu`. Based on iterating all of the cache keys that start with `CacheContentIndex_`, we see that this content needs to be invalidated. So we expire two cache items:

- `MainMenu`
- `CacheContentIndex_MainMenu`

But I want an alternate way to this method. I want to use `CancellationTokenSource` to invalidate caches, so I don't need to store `CacheContentIndex` in a different class.

Thanks in advance.